# Can't compile a simple Bullet Physics application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, bullet

I'm trying to compile [the Hello World](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Hello_World) program from the Bullel Physics Wiki in Visual Studio 2012 Express.
I was able to generate and import the three library projects needed to run the example, but there seems to be a problem when linking them.
In the compile log there are 38 of these errors, repeated a lot of times for each of the libraries.

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in Main.obj
```

I can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Try fooling around with having your program on "debug" or "release".

Comment: It looks like it's saying "You're giving me debug, I want release!"

Comment: Yes, I know, but this is really strange because I'm compiling all the solutions in Debug...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well, its easy to fix once you realize it.

Make sure all your projects match the same Runtime Library per configuration.

More information:
http://www.davidlenihan.com/2008/01/choosing_the_correct_cc_runtim.html

Answer (score 0):

To add to TIHan's answer

One place worth looking is in your `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` section. I wound up noticing that I had a release build linked to my app, when the debug build should have been the one linked. As soon as I changed it, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is the project configuration window, the one where you select which configuration is actually used per-project for the solution's current configuration setting. For instance, I recently had a solution where the release configuration had one of the static library projects set to build the debug version which caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

You could also get this error if a dependent project (producing a .lib) is not included in the solution and therefore has not been built properly.